Default Library of SharePoint Online with Approval management - need explanation for permissions?
When using approval management for default library (Shared Documents) for SharePoint Online, it seems that documents are automatically visible to some people and to others not.
E.g. I saw that my user that is not in Owners group can only see approved documents.
Is there any explanation who can see documents and in what status they can see documents?
How are Designer and Owner connected to the permissions?
Any explanation and link to resource would be greatly appreciated.

Check this documentation and see if it helps to understand SharePoint default permission levels: https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224

@GaneshSanap-MVP That one is related to Sharepoint On-Prem while I need for Sharepoint Online, also I need information specifically for this case

Description/explanation given for Designer and Owner permission levels is same for SPO as well.
